# SWT Tab items run off page when application opened on mac

Tags: java, tabs, swt

I have an application built with SWT. When its tested on Mac the tab items in the tab folder run off the edge of the display screen unless the application has been full screened. Is there a way to stop this happening? I can't find anything from google searches.

If an SWT bug what is the best way to get around this? I was thinking put the tab folder inside a scrollable composite so the tab items can still be viewed in a smaller display.

Thanks

```
public FeedMonitorComposite(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    Composite cmpMain = new Composite(this, SWT.NONE);
    GridLayout gl_cmpMain = new GridLayout(1, false);
    gl_cmpMain.marginHeight = 0;
    gl_cmpMain.marginWidth = 0;
    cmpMain.setLayout(gl_cmpMain);

    cmpSummaries = new Composite(cmpMain, SWT.NONE);
    cmpSummaries.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.TOP, true, false, 1, 1));
    cmpSummaries.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    Composite cmpTabs = new Composite(cmpMain, SWT.NONE);
    cmpTabs.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    cmpTabs.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

    queueTabFolder = new TabFolder(cmpTabs, SWT.NONE);
}
```

[image]

```
private void makeTab(String description, FeedEventsFilter filter) {

    TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(view.getTabFolder(), SWT.NONE);
    tabItem.setText(description);

    Composite composite = new Composite(view.getTabFolder(), SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    tabItem.setControl(composite);

    FeedEventsTabComposite tabView = new FeedEventsTabComposite(composite, SWT.NONE);

    FeedEventsTabController controller = new FeedEventsTabController(context, filter, this, tabItem, tabView);

    tabControllers.add(controller);
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot. Are you using a `Layout` or calling `setBounds()`?

Comment: I can't post a screenshot unfortunately, my boss would not be pleased. The tab folder and tab items are populated from an external feed which causes 10 tab items to be formed. I can display the composite code though.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't have to show any of your top secret ninja data. It's just to understand what you're talking about. You can erase all the stuff you don't want any of us to see with Gimp or similar.

Comment: I'd love to be doin top secret ninja stuff, would take me away from debugging SWT. Throwing stars and nunchuks vs myEclipse and a magic mouse. No contest. Attached a screenshot, the problem is in the top right hand side of the application, the tab item doesn't automatically fit into screen.

Comment: Heh, yeah. Same here :) Ok, can you add the code that creates the tabs?

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior. Looks fine to me: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/OIQCgMO.png).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

The only solution I found was to use `CTabFolder(org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder)` insted of `TabFolder`.